# Need the output of string.Format("{0:0.00;( 0.00;zero}", -100)) in RED color

Tags: c#, excel

Need the output of `string.Format("{0:0.00;( 0.00;zero}", -100))` in RED color

```
worksheet.Cells["Q6"]
    .PutValue("Surgical " + string.Format("{0:0.00;( 0.00;zero}", -100)) + "%)");
```

Need output as Surgical (100%)
(100%) in red color

Comment: I'm assuming this is for an Excel file.. What Excel library are you using?

Comment: Would it better to add excel tag as well?

Comment: So format the cell with the color red.  I am sure the library you are using has that capability.  Looks likes Aspose: https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Changing+the+Font+and+Color+of+a+Cell

Comment: This is simply setting the Cell Font Color to red. It has nothing to do with C#, string.Format, or the like.

Comment: But I don't want whole output in red color. the cell is having Surgical (100%).I just need (100%) in red color

Comment: So color the specific Characters in Red  Google Aspose Cells Characters:  https://apireference.aspose.com/net/cells/aspose.cells/cell/methods/characters